# Photo does not show up to gallery

Tags: android, camera, save, gallery, storage

I'm trying to take a photo using the android camera and telling it to save to the phone's gallery. I think i messed up on the path, but i can't seem to find my error. Could someone help me? I'm very novice at android.

Code to call camera

```
   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                  String uriToFileInExternalStorage = null;
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriToFileInExternalStorage);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

code to handle photo and tell it to go to gallery.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                //check if camera has taken picture by checking request code

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Photo Captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Uri mPath=data.getData();
                 Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

                    mediaScanIntent.setData(mPath);
                    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            }
        }
```

Comment: sample code is based on https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code given here: [Add the Photo to a Gallery](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery)

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

I would suggest you to download example [PhotoIntentActivity](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) to read and understand how to fetch `mCurrentPhotoPath` value.

Comment: I tired, it gives me error. "mCurrentPhotoPath cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: @user2872261 check the updated code. Mistake you are doing is you are not capturing image with actual path name.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
How do i capture image with a path name? I thought captureImageUri was the path name. How do i get the string for mCurrentPhotoPath? I'm getting a null for mCurrentPhotoPath...what gives mCurrentPhotoPath a String?

Comment: likes this

`Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
          File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
          Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
          mediaScanIntent.setData(capturedImageUri);
          this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);`

 ?

Comment: @user2872261 try first

Comment: i did, it didn't work. Not sure what you mean by "capturedImageUri in place of contentUri". I guess that would bypass 'File f= new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)'. But I think my guess is wrong. I'm still not sure how to get mCurrentPhotoPath. Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work in all android versions used in on activity result of camera capture

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I don't know why but the most common approach with sending broadcast with Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE doesn't work for me (Nexus 5x, Nougat 7.1) but your method helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a value to this `uriToFileInExternalStorage`

Sample code:

```
fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(numImages) + ".jpg";

File output = new File(direct + File.separator + fileName); // create
                                                                    // output
while (output.exists()) { // while the file exists
    numImages++; // increment number of images
    fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(numImages) + ".jpg";
    output = new File(outputFolder, fileName);
}

uriToFileInExternalStorage = Uri.fromFile(output);
```

Comment: i don't get it :( sorry Im a novice. I'm not sure where to begin...  Where do i put this "Uri mPath=data.getData();" value to?

Comment: Nope, this is the change for your camera invocation method.. You have set it to null.