# Android - Generate Thumbnails in Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am currently creating a camera app and storing it. However, every time I take a picture, the picture is saved in the directory but is not saved in the Gallery. I think it's all about the generation of thumbnail right after the image has been taken. How can you generate a thumbnail in the gallery?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558188/photo-does-not-show-up-to-gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent mediaScan = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
mediaScan.setData(uri);
context.sendBroadcast(mediaScan);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding files or images programmatically, you have to use [MediaScannerClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) to scan the media file for your sd card.

of you can also use following piece of code:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```